# Stuck on this birthday problem

Tags: probability, birthday

Assume for simplicity that N people, all born in April (a month of 30 days), are collected in a room Consider the event of at least two people in the room being born on the same date of the month, even if in different years, e.g. 1980 and 1985. What is the smallest N so that the probability of this event exceeds 0.5?

Comment: What have you tried? I would try with calculating what is the probability that exactly 2 people share the same date of month, then 3 and then 4 ...

Comment: I tried to do it this way, prob. of at least two people sharing the same birthday = 1 - no couple of persons sharing the same birthday.

Comment: But I'm stuck in the calculation part as it involves factorials.

Comment: @user17616 You are on the right track. Do this for $N=2,3,4$, and you should see a pattern.

Comment: 1 - 30! / { 30^n*(30-n)! } = 0.5. How to figure out n from this?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Approximation_of_number_of_people) suggests an approximation by considering $\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{\frac14+2 \times  \log_e(2) \times 30}$, which is between two integers, so you might try  those to see if they give you  what you want

Comment: @Henry thanks mate, did the job. Answer is 7.

Answer (score 1):

It is very similar to [this.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem)

---

7 persons are enough.

From the article [linked above](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem), we use the same strategy, and we get that $$\frac{30}{30} \times \frac{29}{30} \times \frac{28}{30} \times \frac{27}{30} \times \frac{26}{30} \times \frac{25}{30} \times \frac{24}{30}\le0.5$$ 
The answer follows.